# how to create a register page in php and ajax which checks if a certain username is already there or not without page refresh?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a register.php file which creates new users for my site . But if a person uses a username which is already existing an error is generated only when he enters the whole form and submits . How to implement Ajax/Jquery so as to show it without him submitting the form ?

Comment: Take a look at the following example: [Query Username Availability check](http://www.9lessons.info/2008/12/twitter-used-jquery-plug-in.html)

Comment: You have to consider a graceful fallback in case Javascript is disabled

Comment: Agreed. When the form is submitted, the check should be done again in case the visitor is sans-javascript

Comment: its very easy and u will find the code readymade for you Here's [a link](http://www.bitrepository.com/a-simple-ajax-username-availability-checker.html)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually not too bad if you're familiar with JS/Ajax Basics.

You'll basically need to call a javascript function from your register page..

**HTML on Register Form**

```
<!--This is the textbox with the value we are checking-->
<!--onkeyup can be substituted by any other event you wish to use intead-->
<input onkeyup="checkUsername(this.value);" name="username" id="username" />

<!--This is where we'll display the response-->
<div id="response"></div>
```

That JS function will create an ajax object, and pass the username variable to the PHP page for processing, and will await a response...

**JavaScript**

```
function checkUsername(username){

    //Construct the url, passing the username to the PHP page
    var url= 'checkNameAvailability.php?username=' + encodeURIComponent(username);

    if (ajax.readyState == 4 || ajax.readyState == 0) {
        ajax.open("POST", url, true);
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function (){
            if (ajax.readyState == 4) {    

                //When you get the result from the PHP, put it in the response div
                document.getElementById('response').innerHTML=ajax.responseText;
            }
        }; 
        ajax.send(null);
    }
}

//Just copy and paste this function - don't change it at all.
function getXmlObject() {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            return new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } else {
            showError('Status: Cound not create XmlHttpRequest Object. Consider upgrading your browser.','Please Wait');
        }
    }
```

Then the PHP page, grabs the username variable, processes it in whatever way it needs to (is it available, is it long enough, does it have invalid chars, is it inappropriate, etc..) and returns a response.

**checkNameAvailability.php**

```
<?php

    //Accept a variable called 'username' that we are checking.
    $username=$_REQUEST['username'];

    //Run Checks to see if username is valid
    if ($username=="Dutchie") 
            die ("Username is reserved or already taken");
    if (strlen($username)<5) 
            die("The username is too short.");

   die("Username is Valid");

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Copy this for registration page on HTML:

```
<?php include('vdaemon.php'); ?>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Registration</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
 <link href="samples.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Registration</h1>
 <form id="Register" action="registration_p.php" method="POST" runat="vdaemon" disablebuttons="all">
   <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0">
     <tr>
       <td width="130">
         <vllabel validators="UserID,UserIDExist" errclass="error" for="UserID" cerrclass="controlerror">User ID:</vllabel>
       </td>
       <td width="140">
         <input name="UserID" type="text" class="control" id="UserID" size="15">
         <vlvalidator name="UserID" type="required" control="UserID" errmsg="User ID required">
        <vlvalidator name="UserIDExist" type="custom" control="UserID" errmsg="User ID already exist" function="UserIDCheck">
       </td>
       <td width="300" rowspan="7" valign="top">
         <vlsummary class="error" headertext="Error(s) found:" displaymode="bulletlist">
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
        <vllabel errclass="error" validators="Password,PassCmp" for="Password" cerrclass="controlerror">Password:</vllabel>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input name="Password" type="password" class="control" id="Password" size="15">
         <vlvalidator type="required" name="Password" control="Password" errmsg="Password required">
         <vlvalidator name="PassCmp" type="compare" control="Password" comparecontrol="Password2"
           operator="e" validtype="string" errmsg="Both Password fields must be equal">
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
        <vllabel validators="Password,PassCmp" errclass="error" for="Password2" cerrclass="controlerror">Confirm Password:</vllabel>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input name="Password2" type="PASSWORD" class="control" id="Password2" size="15">
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
        <vllabel errclass="error" validators="NameReq,NameRegExp" for="Name" cerrclass="controlerror">Name:</vllabel>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input name="Name" type="text" class="control" id="Name" size="15">
         <vlvalidator type="required" name="NameReq" control="Name" errmsg="Name required">
         <vlvalidator type="regexp" name="NameRegExp" control="Name" regexp="/^[A-Za-z'\s]*$/" errmsg="Invalid Name">
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
         <vllabel errclass="error" validators="EmailReq,Email" for="Email" cerrclass="controlerror">E-mail:</vllabel>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input name="Email" type="TEXT" class="control" id="Email" size="15">
         <vlvalidator type="required" name="EmailReq" control="Email" errmsg="E-mail required">
         <vlvalidator type="format" format="email" name="Email" control="Email" errmsg="Invalid E-mail">
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td colspan=2>
         <input name="Agreement" type="checkbox" id="Agreement" value="1">
         <vllabel errclass="error" validators="Agreement" for="Agreement">I agree with the terms of service</vllabel>
         <vlvalidator type="required" name="Agreement" control="Agreement" errmsg="Agreement checkbox must be selected">
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td colspan="2">
         <input type="submit" class="control" value="Register">
         <input type="reset" class="control" value="Reset">
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
 <?php VDEnd(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think, the best moment to check username availability, is when username textfield lose its focus (onblur event). the most sites i visit implements such behavior

Answer (score 0):

You could do on form submit, or on blur - or even set timeout when they stop typing assuming they've finished entering their desired username. Then just use ajax to do a lookup of the username. You could also use $.ajax for a few extra options.